# EF7 RC1: There is already an object named '' in the database

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

**Disclaimer**:
I am aware that there are other questions with a title similar to mine. However, other people were not using EF7 RC1 and the pm commands are different.

My problem is that no matter what i do, i cannot get EF7 to create my table. Also, i cannot -force anything or -ignorechanges or even -script as it seems those options were removed from the commands.

My context is

```
public class EventsContext : DbContext//ContextBase
    {
        public DbSet<Publisher> Publishers { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[Constants.Database.CONTEXT_NAME].ConnectionString);
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            const string entityName = "Publisher";
            builder.HasSequence<long>(entityName).StartsAt(1).IncrementsBy(1);

            builder.Entity<Publisher>(o =>
            {
                o.HasKey(x => x.Id);
                o.Property(x => x.Id).HasDefaultValueSql($"NEXT VALUE FOR {entityName}");
                o.Property(x => x.LoggedUserId).IsRequired();
                o.Property(x => x.CreatedDate).IsRequired().HasDefaultValue(DateTime.SpecifyKind(DateTime.UtcNow, DateTimeKind.Utc));
                o.Property(x => x.UpdatedDate).IsRequired();
                o.Property(x => x.Deleted).IsRequired().HasDefaultValue(false);
                o.Property(x => x.RowVersion).ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate().IsConcurrencyToken();

                o.ToTable(Constants.Database.TableNames.PUBLISHER);
                o.Property(x => x.Name).HasMaxLength(Constants.DataFields.Length.MEDIUM_TEXT);
                o.Property(x => x.Email).HasMaxLength(Constants.DataFields.Length.LONG_TEXT);
                o.Property(x => x.FacebookAccount).HasMaxLength(Constants.DataFields.Length.LONG_TEXT);
                o.Property(x => x.TwitterAccount).HasMaxLength(Constants.DataFields.Length.LONG_TEXT);
            });
            builder.Ignore<Event>();
        }
    }
```

Thats me just playing with sequences and rowversion basically.

My publisher class is

```
public class Publisher
{

    public virtual long LoggedUserId { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime UpdatedDate { get; set; }
    public virtual byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }

    public virtual long Id { get; protected set; }
    public virtual bool Deleted { get; set; }
    public virtual string FacebookAccount { get; set; }
    public virtual string TwitterAccount { get; set; }
    public virtual string Email { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Event> Events { get; set; }

}
```

After

```
add-migration init
```

I get

```
 public partial class init : Migration
    {
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.CreateSequence(
                name: "Publisher");
            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "Publisher",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<long>(nullable: false, defaultValueSql: "NEXT VALUE FOR Publisher"),
                    CreatedDate = table.Column<DateTime>(nullable: false, defaultValue: new DateTime(2016, 2, 24, 14, 50, 56, 456, DateTimeKind.Unspecified)),
                    Deleted = table.Column<bool>(nullable: false, defaultValue: false),
                    Email = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    FacebookAccount = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    LoggedUserId = table.Column<long>(nullable: false),
                    Name = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    RowVersion = table.Column<byte[]>(nullable: true),
                    TwitterAccount = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    UpdatedDate = table.Column<DateTime>(nullable: false)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_Publisher", x => x.Id);
                });
        }

        protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.DropSequence("Publisher");
            migrationBuilder.DropTable("Publisher");
        }
    }
```

and after

```
update-database
```

I get

> Applying migration '20160224145056_init'.
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): There is already an
>   object named 'Publisher' in the database.    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
>   Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String
>   methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout,
>   Boolean asyncWrite)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()    at
>   Microsoft.Data.Entity.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.<>c.<ExecuteNonQuery>b__13_0(DbCommand
>   cmd, IRelationalConnection con)    at
>   Microsoft.Data.Entity.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.Execute[T](IRelationalConnection
>   connection, Func`3 action, String executeMethod, Boolean
>   openConnection, Boolean closeConnection)    at
>   Microsoft.Data.Entity.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(IRelationalConnection
>   connection, Boolean manageConnection)    at
>   Microsoft.Data.Entity.Storage.RelationalCommandExtensions.ExecuteNonQuery(IEnumerable`1
>   commands, IRelationalConnection connection)    at
>   Microsoft.Data.Entity.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Execute(IEnumerable`1
>   relationalCommands)    at
>   Microsoft.Data.Entity.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String
>   targetMigration)    at
>   Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String
>   targetMigration, String contextType)    at
>   Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabaseImpl(String
>   targetMigration, String contextType)    at
>   Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_1.<.ctor>b__0()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action
>   action) ClientConnectionId:c34ffd41-714b-4412-a20f-8e18a58b58c1 Error
>   Number:2714,State:6,Class:16 There is already an object named
>   'Publisher' in the database.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that i have duplicate names on the database. The sequences and the tables have the same name.